# Proguard screws up my inner AsyncTask

Tags: android, proguard

I have the following crash in my obfuscated program:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.me.c
```

In my mapping.txt I can see

> org.me.MyActivity$MyTask -> org.me.c

In the corresponding source I have:

```
public class MyActivity {
private static class MyTask extends AsyncTask .... { ...}
}

public void onCreate() {
    ...
       myTask = new MyTask();
       myTask.execute().
}

}
```

I do not do any dynamic loading of `MyTask`. Why can it not find the obfuscated name?

Comment: It might help if you posted the content of your `proguard-project.txt`.

Comment: Why are you using `static` in class definition?

Comment: @rom4ek It's a common thing when using AsyncTask in an Activity. Are you asking for a reason?